# Conditional Subtraction of rows in Python Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to solve a problem at hand as explained. I have a Dataframe as shown below:

```
Date    Item    Type    Qty Price
1/1/18  Orange  Add     100 25
5/1/18  Orange  Add     20  40
8/1/18  Orange  Add     40  20
18/1/18 Orange  Add     10  35
27/2/18 Orange  Sub     100 55
15/4/18 Orange  Sub     30  45
```

and I want to get the intermediate Dataframe like below:

```
Date    Item    Type    Qty Price   Diff
1/1/18  Orange  Add     0   25      30
5/1/18  Orange  Add     0   40      5
8/1/18  Orange  Add     30  20      25
18/1/18 Orange  Add     10  35
```

and then the final Dataframe I want it like this below:

```
Date    Item    Type    Qty Price
8/1/18  Orange  Add     30  20
18/1/18 Orange  Add     10  35
```

NOTE: Diff is a difference of Sub and Add Price. And Qty is also updated with Qty of Sub subtracted from Qty of Add.

Could anyone of you please help with the way it can be achieved. I was trying with groupby, apply and transform but till now I have not got this.

I have below code, still in development and not complete:

```
def FruitSummary():
    df = pd.DataFrame([
               ['01/1/18',   'Orange',   'Add',  100,    25],
               ['05/1/18',   'Orange',   'Add',   20,    40],
               ['08/1/18',   'Orange',   'Add',   40,    20],
               ['18/1/18',   'Orange',   'Add',   10,    35],
               ['27/2/18',   'Orange',   'Sub',  100,    55],
               ['15/4/18',   'Orange',   'Sub',   30,    45],
               ['02/1/18',   'Banana',   'Add',  110,     7],
               ['04/1/18',   'Banana',   'Add',   20,     9],
               ['11/1/18',   'Banana',   'Add',   40,     4],
               ['10/2/18',   'Banana',   'Add',   10,     3],
               ['15/3/18',   'Banana',   'Sub',  100,     9],
               ['15/4/18',   'Banana',   'Sub',   50,     8],
               ['10/3/18',   'Kiwi',     'Add',   80,    29],
               ['12/3/18',   'Berry',    'Add',   25,     5],
               ['18/4/18',   'Berry',    'Add',   15,     8]],
       columns=['Date',      'Item',     'Type', 'Qty',  'Price'])

    print(df)

    def fruit_stat(dfIN):
        print(dfIN)
        print((dfIN['Type'] == 'Sub').unique(), (dfIN['Type'] == 'ODD').unique())

        if len(dfIN) > 1 and (True in (dfIN['Type'] == 'Sub').unique()):
            print(dfIN['Item'].iloc[1], "'len > 1'", "'Sub True'")

dfFS = df.groupby(['Item']).apply(fruit_stat)
print(dfFS)
```

Comment: How does `Qty` changes from 100 to 0 , 20 to 0 , 40 to 30 etc ? What is the logic behind this ? Why there is no `Diff` entry for 4th row ? update the same in your question

Comment: Each row of Sub is used to Subtract the Qty if it is greater than 0. Example the first Add row is subtracted with first Sub row and here Qty was equal so the net Qty remains 0. For the second Add row second Sub row is used but since second Sub row has Qty greater than Qty of Add row so it is made zero and the remaining difference is carried to the third Add row. And the third Add row Qty is updated with the balance of the second Sub row.

Comment: Please avoid *"Give me the codez"* questions. Instead show the script you are working on and state where the problem is. Also see [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/608639)

Answer (score 0):

I am able to find some solution, not sure if it is optimal or there might be better solution for the same.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['01/1/18',   'Orange',   'Add',  100,    25],
                   ['05/1/18',   'Orange',   'Add',   20,    40],
                   ['08/1/18',   'Orange',   'Add',   40,    20],
                   ['18/1/18',   'Orange',   'Add',   10,    35],
                   ['27/2/18',   'Orange',   'Sub',  100,    55],
                   ['15/4/18',   'Orange',   'Sub',   30,    45],
                   ['02/1/18',   'Banana',   'Add',  110,     7],
                   ['04/1/18',   'Banana',   'Add',   20,     9],
                   ['11/1/18',   'Banana',   'Add',   40,     4],
                   ['10/2/18',   'Banana',   'Add',   10,     3],
                   ['15/3/18',   'Banana',   'Sub',  100,     9],
                   ['15/4/18',   'Banana',   'Sub',   50,     8],
                   ['10/3/18',   'Kiwi',     'Add',   80,    29],
                   ['12/3/18',   'Berry',    'Add',   25,     5],
                   ['18/4/18',   'Berry',    'Add',   15,     8],
                   ['16/3/18',   'Cherry',   'Add',   25,     5],
                   ['21/4/18',   'Cherry',   'Sub',   25,     8],
                   ['19/3/18',   'Grapes',   'Add',   25,     5],
                   ['23/4/18',   'Grapes',   'Sub',   15,     8]],
          columns=['Date',      'Item',     'Type', 'Qty',  'Price'])


def FruitSummary(df):
    df['CumSum'] = df.groupby(['Item', 'Type'])['Qty'].cumsum()
    print(df)

    def fruit_stat(dfg):
        if dfg[dfg['Type'] == 'Sub']['Qty'].count():
            subT = dfg[dfg['Type'] == 'Sub']['CumSum'].iloc[-1]
            dfg['Qty'] = np.where((dfg['CumSum'] - subT) <= 0, 0, dfg['Qty'])
            dfg = dfg[dfg['Qty'] > 0]
            if(len(dfg) > 0):
                dfg['Qty'].iloc[0] = dfg['CumSum'].iloc[0] - subT

        return dfg

    dfFS = df.groupby(['Item'], as_index=False).apply(fruit_stat).drop(['CumSum'], axis=1).reset_index(drop=True)
    print(dfFS)
```

And the above code produces the answer like this below:

```
      Date    Item Type  Qty  Price
0  11/1/18  Banana  Add   20      4
1  10/2/18  Banana  Add   10      3
2  12/3/18   Berry  Add   25      5
3  18/4/18   Berry  Add   15      8
4  19/3/18  Grapes  Add   10      5
5  10/3/18    Kiwi  Add   80     29
6  08/1/18  Orange  Add   30     20
7  18/1/18  Orange  Add   10     35
```